# Crash when passing string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My code crashes when passing a string parameter.
Can someone help me sort this? :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"abc"]) {

        MyVC *myvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        myvc.itemstring=@"dsdsds";

    }

}
```

ERROR

> -[UIViewController itemstring:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc89b0028d0
>
> 2016-10-14 14:54:24.118 Myapp[7824:109039] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIViewController itemstring:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fc89b0028d0'

MyVC

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyVC : UIViewController {
    NSString* itemstring;    
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* itemstring;

@end
```

Comment: Update your question with MyVC controller

Comment: show the error.

Comment: whats the use of NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender; in here

Comment: What's in the crash log? And which line is crashing?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I imagine the OP is passing the indexPath from `didSelectRow` into the `performSegue` call. Quite a good way of doing it.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, that's exactly how i am doing it.

Comment: `[segue destinationViewController]` seems to be a `UIViewController` object and not a `MyVC` object. In InterfaceBuilder, you didn't set the class to the `UIViewController` to `MyVC`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line in the error...

> -[UIViewController itemstring:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc89b0028d0

This suggests that the destination of the segue is a `UIViewController` and not a `MyVC`.

You probably haven't set the subclass correctly in the storyboard.

You can update it here...

[image]

by changing the `Class` to `MyVC`.